# React / Redux / JavaScript: How to pass a callback in string format then in renderer make it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a customer care chatbot which replies automatically according to what the customer input. In some use cases, I want to render not just text, but also button in the message. For example, the reply of bot might looks like:

```
const reply_msg = "<p>Do you mean you have some problems about blue screen?</p>
<ul>
    <li><button onclick={this._handleOnClickYes}>Yes</button></li>
    <li><button onclick={this._handleOnClickNo}>No</button></li>
</ul>"
```

This code is in my reducer, and I pass this to app state:
    return [...state, new_msg]

The this._handleOnClickYes is what I want to call the component's callback:

```
export class Messages extends React.Component {
    ....

    _handleOnClickYes(e){
        this.props.sendQuery("Yes");
        // then do something with e
    }

    _handleOnClickNo(e){
        this.props.sendQuery("No");
        // then do something with e
    }

    render(){
        return(
              <div>
                <table className="message_table>
                  {this.props.messages.map(msg => {
                      <tr className="msg-class"><td>{msg}</td></tr>
                      }
                  )}
        ）
    }
}
```

However, when the component receive the props, it can not recognize the callback as string, how I can make such dynamic button and pass the string to the component and then make it as a onclick callback function in the component?

Thanks,

Comment: I found one solution myself, pass the message as object to component props, then render with function inside component, not outside. But I still open to learn new method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you're open to some modifications in the code? I think it might be beneficial for you to store the messages as objects, rather than string.

```
const reply_msg = {
  text: "Do you mean you have some problems about blue screen?",
  expectResponse: true
}

export class Messages extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="message_table>
          {this.props.messages.map(msg =>
            <tr className="msg-class">
              <td>
                {msg.text}
                {msg.expectResponse &&
                  <ul>
                    <li><button onclick={this._handleOnClickYes}>Yes</button></li>
                    <li><button onclick={this._handleOnClickNo}>No</button></li>
                  </ul>
                }
              </td>
            </tr>
          )}
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Doing it in such fashion will give you few important benefits:

- You'll no longer have to store a view information (the HTML in the string) in the state, making it easier to manage and modify,
- having the UI logic only in the component will make your app much more resistant to errors. You'll no longer have to remember to change the UI in a string when the component will change (imagine you'll want to rename those _handleXXX callbacks),
- You'll no longer have to worry about React not recognising anything in the string.

Comment: Thanks, it's same as my new solution, but your tips are great!